# Scholarly opinion of the Open English Bible

Tags: translation-philosophy

My essential question is what is the scholarly view of the Open English Bible (http://openenglishbible.org/)? How does it compare to the NIV or NRSV? Is there a known bias or other issue with it, apart from the fact that it is currently incomplete? For example, if you saw a verse in a book quoting the OEB, would you feel that it gave you a reasonable interpretation of that verse?

Related: Are there other versions of the Bible that are relatively unrestricted or open? The other one mentioned in the [FAQ of the OEB site](http://openenglishbible.org/faq/) is the [World English Bible](http://ebible.org/web/). As they say, the WEB is more NRSV/ESV, while the OEB is more NIV/NEB. For example:

John 3:1-2 (OEB):

> Now there was a Pharisee named Nicodemus, who was a leading man among his people. 2 This man came to Jesus by night, and said to him: “Rabbi, we know that you are a teacher come from God; for no one could give such signs as you are giving, unless God were with him.”

John 3:1-2 (NIV):

> Now there was a Pharisee, a man named Nicodemus who was a member of the Jewish ruling council. 2 He came to Jesus at night and said, “Rabbi, we know that you are a teacher who has come from God. For no one could perform the signs you are doing if God were not with him.”

John 3:1-2 (WEB):

> Now there was a man of the Pharisees named Nicodemus, a ruler of the Jews. 2 The same came to him by night, and said to him, “Rabbi, we know that you are a teacher come from God, for no one can do these signs that you do, unless God is with him.”

John 3:1-2 (NRSV):

> Now there was a Pharisee named Nicodemus, a leader of the Jews. 2 He came to Jesus[a] by night and said to him, “Rabbi, we know that you are a teacher who has come from God; for no one can do these signs that you do apart from the presence of God.”

I only happened upon the OEB recently and was interested because I am writing a book and find the NIV and NRSV a little restrictive in their permissions and licensing. I'd be happy to describe the whole permissions story, if that were of interest, but it strays from the hermeneutics question.

---

In the end, I've decided to go with the WEB. This is the current draft of the relevant paragraph from the introduction to [my book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0754Q56CC):

> I include Bible verses in my text if it is necessary for the point I am making. Otherwise, when I reference a Bible verse I put it in a footnote of this ebook version. This will save the reader from having to flick back and forth through the Bible while reading, though I encourage you to do so anyway. Read the context and maintain a healthy skepticism of all claims, including mine. I also include a link to the verse so that you can compare different translations and versions. In general, I have used the World English Bible (WEB) because this is the only version that is both in the public domain and written in modern English (the Open English Bible is a second project working towards this, but is currently incomplete). The WEB is based on the American Standard Version which in turn is a revision of the Authorized Version/King James Bible. The WEB therefore combines the familiar feel and authority of the King James with a contemporary readability, while also enabling me to include hundreds of verses without restriction. I originally planned to use the NIV, but the licensing requirements were too onerous and would have limited the distribution of this book. In each verse I quoted, though, I compared the NIV with the WEB to ensure that the meaning was unchanged.

Comment: I was not aware of this interesting project, which should prove quite a boon for authors such as yourself. A cursory glance doesn't reveal anything weird. I should point out that "English" here refers to British English rather than American English (IE, "centre" rather than "center" and such). I like to say, "show me the original and then we can talk about accuracy". But there is no original so accuracy is ultimately not a relevant term.

Comment: I believe they have a US English version, but that's certainly not a huge issue for me

Comment: If you are going to provide a link you could use biblegateway.com which allows things like this: https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%202:11,%204:21,%205:26,%2013:32-33,%2022:34,%2022:61&version=KJV

Comment: My links are mostly to biblegateway and biblehub (when versions are important). But in a Kindle book, you want to be able to read it off-grid. NIV took months to get back to me and offered to license it for 2000(!) copies and US distribution only. Hence the switch to WEB...

Comment: I just came across this and thought it might be of interest to you or others:  https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Bible

Comment: @Ruminator, that is interesting. But what is the source material and philosophy that people are using? I didn't find a page on making a contribution to explain

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea!

Comment: @Ruminator, these translations are done by the community. Quite amazing, but not a source I would necessarily use.

Comment: The project looks very interesting and promising. The downside seems to be that the primary sources would probably not be recognized as authoritative because of a lack of credentials of the contributors.